# Can I use any other encoding other than Base64 while passing client Id & client secret in Authorization header

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can I use any other encoding other than Base64 while passing client Id & client secret in Authorization header while obtaining token from OAuth provider.
Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard "Authorization" basic header must use base 64 encoding. In contrast if you need to use a different mechanism to communicate clientid and secret, indeed you can use given the below conditions are satisfied.

1) You should not use basic authorization header to pass information. (If you use this, you must use base 64 encoding)

2) The server should know how to decode it. In the latest versions of wso2 products you can write custom OAuth client authenticator which knows how to decode your custom information and derive client id and secret. Below is a sample on how to do it.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Writing+A+New+OAuth+Client+Authenticator

Or else the easiest option is, you can pass client id and secret in the body of the request (Not as a header). In this method you don't need to encode it. It's just plain text

Answer (score 0):

You can you use any encoding you want, as long as you are decoding it properly. But the Base64 is the standard.